# How to add an image to a proper position on web page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, web

I tried to add an image (137×30) next to the search bar, but I cannot do it properly. It is supposed to look like this:

[image]

The code for search bar is like this:

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

Adding the image gave me this result:

[image]

How do I make this image align properly?

The code for this webpage as reference if you need to look at it:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<title><?php wp_title( '-', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.ico">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="//s3.amazonaws.com/nwapi/nwmatcher/nwmatcher-1.2.5-min.js"></script>
<script src="//html5base.googlecode.com/svn-history/r38/trunk/js/selectivizr-1.0.3b.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.1.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/ie8.css">
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
!function(){function t(){var t=r("utm_content");if(t){var e=new Date;e.setDate(e.getDate()+30),document.cookie=t+";expires="+e.toGMTString()+";path=/"}else if(document.cookie)for(var o=document.cookie.split(/; */),n=0;n<o.length;n++)if(0===o[n].toLowerCase().trim().indexOf("utm_content=")){t=o[n];break}return t}function e(t){try{console.log(t)}catch(e){alert(t)}}function r(t){var e=top.location.search?top.location.search.substring(1):null;if(e)for(var r=e.split("&"),o=0;o<r.length;o++)if(0===r[o].toLowerCase().trim().indexOf(t+"="))return r[o];return null}var o="",n=r("mctest");if(n)e("dnr tag version: 20160125"),o="http://localhost:8080/rip/library/dnr/mcDnrTag.debug.js";else{var a=t(),c="";a&&(c=top.location.search?0<=top.location.search.indexOf("utm_content")?top.location.search:top.location.search+"&"+a:"?"+a,o="https://script.advertiserreports.com/redirector/dnr"+c)}if(o){var i=document.createElement("script");i.src=o,i.type="text/javascript",scriptTag=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],scriptTag.parentNode.appendChild(i)}}();
</script>
<?php 
    wp_head();
    if(function_exists('ot_get_option')) 
        echo ot_get_option( 'cnkt_google_analytics' );
?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php 
    $cats = '';
    foreach(get_the_category() as $category)
        $cats .= $category->slug . ' '; 
?>
<div id="container" class="<?php echo $post->post_name; echo ' '. $cats; ?>">
    <a href="#page-content" class="skip-to-content" tabindex="0">Skip to main content</a>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header class="site-header" role="banner">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">  
                    <ul class="secondary hide-for-medium-down">
                        <li class="mailinglist"><a href="/join-our-mailing-list/">Join our Mailing List</a></li>
                        <li class="quote"><a href="/request-quote/">Request a Quote</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="nav-wrap"> 
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.png" /></a>
                        </div>
                    <div class="sub-wrap hide-for-medium-down">          
                        <nav id="utilitynav" role="navigation">
                            <ul id="menu-utility" class="menu">
                                <li id="menu-item-2398" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2398 menu-item-news">
                                    <a href="http://test-shaver-inc.pantheonsite.io/resource-center/news/">News &amp; Events</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-2397" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2397 menu-item-contact-us">
                                    <a href="http://www.shaverinc.com/contact-us/">Contact Us</a>

                                </li>
                                <li class="linkedin">
                                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/shaver-industries-inc<?php echo '-' ?>" target="_blank">
                                        <em class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></em>
                                        <span class="offscreen">LinkedIn</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="twitter">
                                    <a href="https://twitter.com/shaver_inc" target="_blank">
                                        <em class="fa fa-twitter"></em>
                                        <span class="offscreen">Twitter</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="facebook">
                                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ShaverIndustriesInc?fref=ts" target="_blank">
                                        <em class="fa fa-facebook"></em>
                                        <span class="offscreen">Facebook</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="youtube">
                                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6zDe4BG-OAuV4_JLrmu-JA" target="_blank">
                                        <em class="fa fa-youtube"></em>
                                        <span class="offscreen">YouTube</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                     <?php /*if ( has_nav_menu('utility-menu')):?>
                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'utility-menu', 'container'=>'' ) ); 
                        dynamic_sidebar('social-media'); ?>
                     <?php endif;*/ ?>
                     <?php
                        if ( function_exists( 'ot_get_option' ) ) {
                            if (ot_get_option('cnkt_phone')) {
                                 echo '<span class="number">'.ot_get_option('cnkt_phone').'</span>';
                            }
                        }   
                     ?>             
                      </nav>
                     <?php get_search_form(); ?>   
                    </div>    
                    </div>                          
                    <nav id="mnav" class="hide-for-medium-down" role="navigation">
               <?php if ( has_nav_menu('primary-menu')):?>
                  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'container'=>'' ) ); ?> 
               <?php endif; ?>  

                  </nav>     
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div id="mnav-toggle" class="nav-toggle hide-for-medium-up" aria-hidden="true">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">
               <span class="one"></span>
               <span class="two"></span>
               <span class="three"></span>
            </a>
            </div> 
        </header>
        <div id="mobile-nav"><div class="wrap"></div></div>
        <?php if(!is_page('home')){
           get_template_part('includes/page-banner');
        } ?>
        <!-- #page-content -->
        <div id="page-content">
```

Comment: Please post the generated HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: Sorry the source code of this web page is PHP....

Comment: Yes, but when you open it in a web browser, it will generate HTML. Can you post that HTML?

Comment: There is not enough space for the images, so they go in the row below.

Comment: Your image width and height break the div container. You need CSS to fix this, not PHP.

Comment: Um.. no, if you view the page, then right click in your browser and show source, you should see HTML.  On another note, you can use CSS positioning to get the pic where you want..  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: fyi The form tag automatically adds line breaks before and after in most browsers. (quite annoying actually), so CSS is really the only way to fix this

Comment: thanks for help, but I don't know which position type I should use? Plus, the source in HTML version is too long to put in the description...

Comment: Here is the link for source code: view-source:http://www.shaverinc.com/  thanks !!!

Comment: Duane, can you show me which position property I should use? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out by myself, I should use div+table to figure this out

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 600px;">
                      <table style="width: 100%">
                     <tr>
                     <td width="80%"><?php get_search_form(); ?></td>
                     <td width="20%"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/flags.png"></td>
                    </tr> 
                    </table>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID outside of your `input` and `img` and add below css. Demo example added like this. See at fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wD5T9/

**HTML**

```
<div id='searchWrapper'>
    <input id='searchBox' style='width:250px; border:1px solid #cccccc; border-radius:7px 7px 7px 7px; padding:5px 28px 5px 10px; margin-top:14px; margin-left:50px;height:18px;' type='text' placeholder='Search'/>
    <img src='http://www.q-park.ie/Portals/8/images/search-icon.png'/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#searchWrapper img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Hi Being, thanks for help, but it doesn't work... The image still shows under the search bar

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your problem....[image]

Your **Html**

```
<div class="searchform">
<form method="get" action="http://www.shaverinc.com">
    <label for="search" class="offscreen">Search Products</label>
   <input type="search" placeholder="Search Products" id="s" name="s" value="">
   <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i><span class="offscreen">Submit</span></button>
</form>
</div>
<div class="flags">Hello</div>
```

Your **CSS** Here.....

```
.searchform {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
height: 34px;
width: 90%;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}
.flags{
display: block;
width: 9%;
height: 34px;
position: relative;
float: left;
background: #ccc;
}
```

Manipulate the width according to your need...

Comment: What happened dude ... Is your problem solved.....?? Atleast tell us something....